# How to make a fake VBA.Collection

Tags: .net, com

I have gone thru so much (needless) pain over interop with VB6 it's not even funny, so I am done with trying to play by VB6 rules, and I'm done looking around for old VB6 COM dlls. Just sick of it.

Unfortunately, I have to talk back and forth to VB6. Which requires passing a VBA.Collection back and forth.

I have adapted an implementation for vb.net, and had to fix the key coming to the add, because it's null when missing.

```vb
Public Class VBACollection
  Implements VBA._Collection

  Private _items As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object)

  Public Sub Add(ByRef Item As Object, Optional ByRef Key As Object = Nothing, Optional ByRef Before As Object = Nothing, Optional ByRef After As Object = Nothing) Implements VBA._Collection.Add
    ' Ignoring the Before and After params for simplicity
    Key = If(Key, Item)
    _items.Add(Key, Item)
  End Sub

  Public Function Count() As Integer Implements VBA._Collection.Count
    Return _items.Count
  End Function

  Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator Implements VBA._Collection.GetEnumerator, System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return _items.Values.GetEnumerator()
  End Function

  Public Function Item(ByRef Index As Object) As Object Implements VBA._Collection.Item
    Return _items(Index)
  End Function

  Public Sub Remove(ByRef Index As Object) Implements VBA._Collection.Remove
    _items.Remove(Index)
  End Sub
End Class
```

However, this does not work with VB6. VB6 says:

> "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected
>   interface"

The class it's talking about here is my class that uses VBACollection instead of VBA.Collection. VBACollection is not an identical stand-in for VBA.Collection. I'd like to find out why and try to fake COM out into accepting it.

If I can successfully do this, I will no longer have to deal with VBA.dll or VBA.Interop.dll and the build time errors that just come out of nowhere telling me I can't compile when it was working yesterday, etc.

I want to make the VB6 client believe that I have the real vba collection. I don't care where it's registered; I don't need mine registered but I need that same guid I suppose.

This is not a duplicate unless the other article shows how to get rid of having to reference VBA.dll in your projects. I just want it in that one project that has to reference VBA._Collection and that's it. And if there's a way to get rid of even that, so much the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you ought to be in the ballpark by implementing the VBA._Collection interface.  The error message suggests that you forgot to make it `<ComVisible>`.  Make sure you added the correct reference with Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select c:\windows\syswow64\msvbvm60.dll

The best way to get it implemented is by using the VB.NET Collection class, it reproduces the very unusual behavior of the VBA Collection most closely:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
Public Class CollectionImpl
    Implements VBA.Collection
    Private impl As New Collection

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return impl.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Sub Add(ByRef Item As Object, Optional ByRef Key As Object = Nothing, Optional ByRef Before As Object = Nothing, Optional ByRef After As Object = Nothing) Implements VBA._Collection.Add
        impl.Add(Item, CStr(Key), Before, After)
    End Sub

    Public Function Count() As Integer Implements VBA._Collection.Count
        Return impl.Count
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerator Implements VBA._Collection.GetEnumerator
        Return impl.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Function Item(ByRef Index As Object) As Object Implements VBA._Collection.Item
        Return impl.Item(Index)
    End Function

    Public Sub Remove(ByRef Index As Object) Implements VBA._Collection.Remove
        If TypeOf Index Is String Then
            impl.Remove(CStr(Index))
        Else
            impl.Remove(CInt(Index))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Untested, I don't have the tooling installed anymore.  Ought to be in the ballpark :)

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try it and test it; that will take a day.

Answer (score 0):

Good news. You can fake a `VBA.Collection` without any COM-interop references in your .Net project.

I give the credit to the last answer here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4574645-6f63-49d3-a225-a6c138945ca9/return-vbacollection-from-vbnet-to-vb6-via-com-interop?forum=vbinterop

First of all, you can receive a `VBA.Collection` from VB6 to VB.Net simply by declaring the argument in vb.net as `Object`. No special marshaling is required.

The .net assembly containing these types needs to be COM visible and needs to register for COM interop; but again, no references are required.

Then to return one back to VB6, the following Interface needs to be on signatures of methods' return values. You don't need to reference to `VBA` or `msvbvm60.dll` for this to work.

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

''' <summary>
''' IVBACollection mimics VBA.Collection without needing any COM Interop reference
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<ComImport(), TypeLibType(CShort(&H1050)), Guid("A4C46780-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB"), DefaultMember("Item")> _
Public Interface IVBACollection
  Inherits IEnumerable

  <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType:=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0)> _
  Function Item(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef Index As Object) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> Object

  <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType:=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(1)> _
  Sub Add(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef Item As Object, _
                    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> Optional ByRef Key As Object = Nothing, _
                    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> Optional ByRef Before As Object = Nothing, _
                    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> Optional ByRef After As Object = Nothing)

  <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType:=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(2)> _
  Function Count() As Integer

  <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType:=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(3)> _
  Sub Remove(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef Index As Object)

  <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType:=MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(-4)> _
  Shadows Function GetEnumerator() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalType:="", MarshalTypeRef:=GetType(EnumeratorToEnumVariantMarshaler), MarshalCookie:="")> IEnumerator

End Interface
```

If you need to create a VBA.Collection and send it back, you just create and populate an instance of this class and pass it back to VB6, which consumes it just fine. Just remember your signature needs to be `IVBACollection` and not `VBACollection`.

```vb
Public Class VBACollection
  Implements IVBACollection

  Private _Collection As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()

  Public Sub Add(ByRef Item As Object, _
                 Optional ByRef Key As Object = Nothing, _
                 Optional ByRef Before As Object = Nothing, _
                 Optional ByRef After As Object = Nothing) Implements IVBACollection.Add

    Dim sKey As String = Nothing
    If Not TypeOf Key Is System.Reflection.Missing And Key IsNot Nothing Then
      sKey = Key.ToString
    End If

    Dim oBefore As Object = Nothing
    If IsNumeric(Before) Then
      oBefore = CInt(Before)
    ElseIf Not TypeOf Before Is System.Reflection.Missing And Before IsNot Nothing Then
      oBefore = Before.ToString
    End If

    Dim oAfter As Object = Nothing
    If IsNumeric(After) Then
      oAfter = CInt(After)
    ElseIf Not TypeOf After Is System.Reflection.Missing And After IsNot Nothing Then
      oAfter = After.ToString
    End If

    _Collection.Add(Item, sKey, oBefore, oAfter)

  End Sub

  Public Function Count() As Integer Implements IVBACollection.Count
    Return _Collection.Count
  End Function

  Public Function Item(ByRef Index As Object) As Object Implements IVBACollection.Item
    If IsNumeric(Index) Then
      Return _Collection.Item(CInt(Index))

    ElseIf _Collection.Contains(Index.ToString) Then
      Return _Collection.Item(Index.ToString)

    Else
      Err.Raise(5, Description:="Item '" + Index.ToString + "' not in collection.")
      Return ErrorToString(5)
    End If
  End Function

  Public Sub Remove(ByRef Index As Object) Implements IVBACollection.Remove
    If IsNumeric(Index) Then
      _Collection.Remove(CInt(Index))
    Else
      _Collection.Remove(Index.ToString)
    End If
  End Sub

  Default Public ReadOnly Property Defaultprop(ByVal Index As Object) As Object
    Get
      Return Item(Index)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator Implements IVBACollection.GetEnumerator, System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return _Collection.GetEnumerator
  End Function

End Class
```